# Arrangement of the word MATHEMATICS if last spot must have the letter 'T'

Tags: permutations

How many ways can the word MATHEMATICS be arranged if the last letter must be a T?

My solution:

There are $2$ possible choices for the last letter (There are $2$ different T's), which leaves $10$ choices for other places. However, the letters 'M' and 'A' are repeated twice. Therefore, the answer is $$\frac{10! \times 2}{2! \times 2!}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: There isn't really any choice for the last letter. It must be a $T$. Thus the correct result is half of what you gave.

Comment: But there are 2 different 'T's

Comment: And what is their difference? The point is that they are indistinguishable so swapping them doesn't form a new combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to think of this is the number of arrangements of
$$MATHEMAICS$$
(note the missing $T$ wich is reserved for the last letter). The solution now is simply
$$\frac{10!}{2!\cdot 2!} = \frac{10!}4$$
due to the same argument as you noted (double $A$ and $M$, all other letters unique).

Comment: Are there not $2$ choices for the last letter, since there are $2$ T's?

Comment: @AspiringMathlete In the new problem there is only one $T$. The old problem is basically equivalent. We "took away" one $T$ from the pool of letters to be arranged.